# Python- When I move items in one list to anther list, some items are missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I move items from list "X" to anther list "A", but some items are missing.

Here is my code.

```
X=list(range(2,11))
print(X)
A=list()
for x in X:
       A.append(x)
       X.remove(x)
       print("A is ", A)
       print("X is ", X)
```

I expected `X =[], A =[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],`

but the result was

```
A is  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
X is  [3, 5, 7, 9]
```

the odd numbers aren't moved.
I want to know why they are not moved and how to move them.

I'm new to python programing, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't change list while iterating over it

Comment: This is a classic mistake: looping over a list while modifying it. Python keeps track of what the current position in the list `X` is, but since you're removing elements during every iteration, that position is no longer correct. (also, don't name variables `x` and `X` - that's a very bad habit)

Comment: Is there any reason why can't you just move it the normal way? You want to reverse the list?

Comment: You can copy the list and work from the copy, e.g. `for x in list(X):`

Comment: Thanks guys, I was making some codes finding out prime numbers from 2 to a given number. And I made two lists, the X from 2 to 10, and the prime number list. Anyway, I found what was problem. Thank you so much..!!!

Comment: Really appreciate your advice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    X=list(range(2,11))
    print(X)
    A=list()
    X=X[::-1]
    while X:
       A.append(X.pop())
       print("A is ", A)
       print("X is ", X)
```

Instead of removing first reverse the X and pop the elements from X and append it to A.

Comment: pop and append it, really helpful!!
If it doens't bother you, may I ask you why the odd numbers remained in X when I tried moving elements??

Comment: That was explained in @Grismar 's comment.

Comment: Thank you!! I forgot to read the commets he wrote...